# Constructor in partial MetataData class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-classes

I have the following partial class, which provides Metadata to my Database first models.

```
namespace Model.Metadata.Routing
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(RoutingMetadata))]
    public partial class Routing
    {

    }

    public partial class RoutingMetadata
    {          
        [DefaultValue("%")]
        public string Slot { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is requied")]
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int BlockStart { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is requied")]
        [DefaultValue(499)]
        public int BlockEnd { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(-1)]       
    }
}
```

Now I want to add a constructor for the Routing Class to default my values,

```
public Routing()
{
  Slot="%";
}
```

Where do I add the constructor?

[EDIT]
Other half of partial Class Routing

```
 public partial class Routing
{      
    public string Slot { get; set; }
    public int BlockStart { get; set; }
    public int BlockEnd { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Um, `Slot` isn't a property of `Routing`... it's a property of `RoutingMetadata`. So your constructor body wouldn't make sense...

Comment: But it is a Member of Routing in the other Partial Class generated by the Database first Model. See edit

Comment: Okay. That would have been useful to know to start with :) Although it's called `RadioRouting` for some reason in your edit. But basically, put the constructor anywhere within either of the class declarations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the constructor in any one of the partial class definitions, it's up to you where you think it makes the most logical sense.

Of course, all parts of a partial class definition need to have the same class name and namespace, or they are different classes. `Routing` and `RadioRouting` are not the same class, because they don't have the same name.

Comment: If i make the constructor in the partial class Routing (at the top of my question) it doesnt know about the value Slot.  Do I have to copy all the values from the other partial class across to this one ?

Comment: No, your constructor _should_ see the properties in the other part of the partial class. If it doesn't, there is something wrong with the partial class definitions, e.g. class name or namespace doesn't match. Partial classes behave just like any other class, except you can split them across multiple files.

Comment: By the way, word of advice: Don't abuse partial classes too much, because it can make your code base hard to maintain. I would only use them when a part of the class is generated by a tool.

Comment: Also, if you _copy_ the properties from one part of the partial to the other, you should get a compile error because of duplicate properties (unless they, are in fact, _not_ part of the same class).

Comment: Well I am making use of Partial Class because Model clqss is generated by EF Tool. I will look again at putting the constructor in there.

Comment: Well, for generated code it's ok, but of course you should _not_ put the the constructor or any other custom code in the generated part because it may get overwritten by the tool. 
Have you checked if both parts of the class are in the same namespace?